# Dimension of Array Missing

Tags: java

```
public jfCategoria() {
    initComponents();
    Listar();
}

private void Listar(){
    DAOCategoria dao = new DAOCategoria();
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    lista = dao.Listar();
    dtm.addColumn ("id");
    dtm.addColumn ("Categoria");
    dtm.addColumn ("Descripcion");
    for (Categoria c : lista) {
        dtm.addRow(new Object[](c.getIdcategoria(), c.getNombre(), c.getDescripcion()))
    }
    tblCategoria.setModel(dtm);
}
```

I don't know why im getting the error...
Can someone help me? Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: you cannot declare an Object[] like the way you're doing

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use braces (`{}`), not parentheses (`()`) to initialize an array:

```
dtm.addRow(new Object[] { c.getIdcategoria(), c.getNombre(), c.getDescripcion() } );
```